# Wifi connection issues with ROS 2 and Humble

Tags: ros, ros2, wifi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having wifi connection issues since upgrade to ROS 2 Humble.
The connection will mostly work, but then drop for some period of time.

I'm posting this "question" and answer here in case others have issues.

It might NOT be related to ROS 2, DDS, or Humble at all.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403954/wifi-issues-in-ubuntu-22-04lts
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1967842

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401891/wifi-connection-issues-with-ros-2-and-humble/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2022-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2022-06-03**:
I'm seeing issues using Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-33-generic with Intel NUC w/ Intel 8260 wireless on robot, and desktop connected to NetGear R7000

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-04**:
I'd suggest posting your edit as an answer.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2022-06-07**:
I will post answer once we are finished testing.   In the mean time, this fix seems to have improved wifi:

I disabled Wi-Fi power management directly by editing:
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
Then changed the value from 3 to 2, saved changes and rebooted.

Still need to do more stress testing with ROS 2 specific  code before I say its the "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disabling power save seemed to fix issues.  I have not reverted with latest kernel updates to see if fixed in standard kernel, but disabling power save fixed issues I was having.

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2023-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0